# A word to describe a product that has been iterated over many times?

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's take a product like the iPhone. It has seen many enhancements and update rounds. From the initial prototype to the current version. What word would there be to describe such a product?

I'm thinking of something like "polished" but without the connotation of something necessarily clean. Just something having seen effort put into it. Any ideas?

Comment: As a side note: _polished_ doesn't necessary connote "clean" or "shiny". From NOAD, _polished_ can mean "accomplished and skillful" (as in a _polished performance_), or it can mean "refined, sophisticated, or elegant".

Answer (score 4):

It's a product that has been **refined** with each iteration. However, refined does sound like it would only apply to high-end products.

From [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/refined)

> Refined - improved to be more precise or exact

Alternatively, you could say it is a product that has **evolved** with each new version. Describing the iPhone as an '*evolving product*' may fit your purpose. It doesn't suggest it's the end of the line and that it will continue to change and improve.

From [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/evolved)

> Evolving - to change or develop slowly often into a better, more complex, or more advanced state : to develop by a process of evolution

Answer (score 2):

***Well-seasoned*** or ***honed*** are indicative of repeated, positive effort.  ***Reworked*** implies that it has been worked on more than once, although it may carry connotations of prior failures.

Answer (score 1):

How about 'improved' or 'matured' which could very well convey the context?

Comment: I think "mature" is a good suggestion, but I also think this answer would be much improved if you either quoted a definition that uses that word in this sense, or maybe found a product review or something that used that word to convey this meaning (as opposed to answering with a question).

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a specific singular word, but would you consider **multi-generation product** as an acceptable phrase?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that improvement is necessarily implied - a humourously critical view might afford answers such as 'cloned', 'bred', 'over-bred', 'mutilated', 're-disassembled'.

Answer (score 0):

The word

> **enhanced**

may fit, to mean that the product went through an improvement process

> [enhance](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/enhance)
>
> verb
>
> *Intensify, increase, or further improve the quality, value, or extent of.*

Answer (score 0):

**consummate**  [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/consummate)

> adj -    having or revealing supreme mastery or skill

As in:

*The iPhone , through its iterations, has become the consummate cell phone.*